# Fixed endpoint and free end time problem

Tags: integration, optimization, definite-integrals, calculus-of-variations, maximum-principle

So I have this problem but I dont know if my solution is right. Can someone help me?

We consider the following fixed endpoint and free end time problem

$\min  \int_{0}^{t_f}1 dt \\
s.t\\
x_{1}{'}(t) = x_2(t) \\
x_{2}{'}(t)) = u(t)\\
x_1(0) = 0\\
x_2(0) = 0\\
x_1(t_f) = 2\\
x_2(t_f) = 2\\
u(t) ∈ [−1, 1] ∀t ∈ [0, t_f].$

The optimal control for this problem is $u^∗ ≡ 1$, which leads to the optimal endtime $t^∗ = 2$.

1.) Calculate the corresponding endtime variation giving a pointwise structured solution.

So what I have done is:
According to the Pontryagin's Maximum Principle, the optimal control for this problem must satisfy the following conditions:

There exists an adjoint state, denoted by p, that is co-state to the state variables and satisfies the adjoint equations:
\begin{align*}
p_{1}{'}(t) &= -p_{2}(t) \
p_{2}{'}(t) &= -p_{1}(t)u(t) \
p_1(t_f) &= 0 \
p_2(t_f) &= 0
\end{align*}
The optimal control must satisfy the following transversality conditions:
\begin{align*}
p_1(0) &= 0 \
p_2(0) &= -1
\end{align*}
The optimal control must satisfy the Hamiltonian equation:
\begin{align*}
H(x, u, p) = p_{1}u + p_{2} &= \max_{u \in [-1, 1]} H(x, u, p) \
\end{align*}
Given the Hamiltonian equation, we can see that the optimal control for this problem is u^∗ = 1.

Next, we can use the optimal control to calculate the endtime variation. To do this, we can consider the problem with a small perturbation in the endtime, say $t_f + Δt_f$. The optimal control for this perturbed problem would also be $u^∗ = 1$, but the corresponding endtime would be $t_f + Δt_f$.

Now, we can use the adjoint state to calculate the sensitivity of the optimal cost with respect to the endtime, which can be expressed as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t_f} 1 dt &= p_{1}(0)x_{1}'(0) + p_{2}(0)x_{2}'(0) \
&= p_{2}(0)
\end{align*}

Therefore, the sensitivity of the optimal cost with respect to the endtime is equal to $p_2(0)$, which is equal to $-1$. This means that a small increase in the endtime would result in a decrease in the optimal cost by $1$.

So, the corresponding endtime variation for this problem would be $-1$.